# Passenger Server on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, passenger

was just wondering if you know what the easiest way to setup passenger on AWS is? Are there any images we can buy? Can't seem to find anything on the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use any Debian or Ubuntu image, then install Phusion Passenger through its official APT repository: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#install_on_debian_ubuntu
This automatically installs all necessary dependencies and provides regular updates. No compilation required.